# How to use the Bing Maps Silverlight Control in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, bing-maps

I have created a Silverlight Application project using the Bing Maps Silverlight Control and it works well.

Now I want to use a frame control in other WPF Application project to show the map. So I want to put the main page of the Silverlight project into the frame. I tried to add reference to the WPF project, but there appeared an error. And using Bing Maps SOAP Services in WPF project doesn't meet requirements, so I must use the Bing Maps Silverlight Control.

I really don't know how to solve the problem. I'll be glad to know any ways to use Bing Maps Silverlight Control in a WPF project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has recently published (23.08.2011) a beta version of a WPF control for Bing Maps. The API is quite the same as Bing Maps Control for Silverlight API so a significant piece of code written for Silverlight version should also work with the WPF control. Here's a blog entry with details: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/08/23/announcing-the-bing-maps-wpf-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a Bing Map control for WPF (e.g. see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/BingMapsWebServiceExample.aspx), you could try to load the webpage that hosts the silverlight control inside your WPF app. You could achieve this by using the WebBrowser control or some similar method, and setting the URL to your silverlight page.

Cheers,
G.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

I have seen the website you mentioned already, it's a copy from MSDN article:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx. I won't use Bing Maps SOAP Services, because I strive to make the application more dynamic and more practical.

Actually, I would like to build a client application embed LBS using Bing Maps. Publish a website containing the Silverlight application may be the last choice if I cannot embed the Silverlight application in my WPF application. So I look for a better idea to solve the problem, don't build a website as far as possible.